# Change PHP code to MVC Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've made a recursive function to display the menu as a tree (each domain to have sub domains, and so on). The code works as is with a database, but I want to make it MVC to include it into my Codeigniter project.

I've tried splitting everything related to the database into the model, and so on... but doesn't work. You can see below the raw code, maybe someone can guide me how to change it to the MVC model. Thanks!!

```
<?php

    $result = mysql_query("select id_domeniu, nume_domeniu, parent from domenii");


    $menu = array(
        'menus' => array(),
        'parent_menus' => array()
    );


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //creates entry into menus array with current menu id ie. $menus['menus'][1]
        $menu['menus'][$row['id_domeniu']] = $row;
        //creates entry into parent_menus array. parent_menus array contains a list of all menus with children
        $menu['parent_menus'][$row['parent']][] = $row['id_domeniu'];
    }


    function buildMenu($parent, $menu) {
    $html = "";
    if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$parent])) {
        $html .= "<ul>";
        foreach ($menu['parent_menus'][$parent] as $menu_id) {
                if (!isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                $html .= "<li><a href='#'>" . $menu['menus'][$menu_id]['nume_domeniu'] . "</a></li>";
            }
            if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                $html .= "<li><a href='#'>" . $menu['menus'][$menu_id]['nume_domeniu'] . "</a>";
                $html .= buildMenu($menu_id, $menu);
                $html .= "</li>";
            }
        }
        $html .= "</ul>";
    }
    return $html;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<?php echo buildMenu(0, $menu);; ?>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

My attempt:

Model:

```
<?php
class New_menu_model extends CI_Model {
    function get_domains() {
        $result = $this->db->get ( 'domenii' );
        return $result;

        $menu = array(
                'menus' => array(),
                'parent_menus' => array()
        );


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //creates entry into menus array with current menu id ie. $menus['menus'][1]
            $menu['menus'][$row['id_domeniu']] = $row;
            //creates entry into parent_menus array. parent_menus array contains a list of all menus with children
            $menu['parent_menus'][$row['parent']][] = $row['id_domeniu'];
        }
    }

    function buildMenu($parent, $menu) {
        $html = "";
        if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$parent])) {
            $html .= "<ul>";
            foreach ($menu['parent_menus'][$parent] as $menu_id) {
                if (!isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                    $html .= "<li><a href='#'>" . $menu['menus'][$menu_id]['nume_domeniu'] . "</a></li>";
                }
                if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                    $html .= "<li><a href='#'>" . $menu['menus'][$menu_id]['nume_domeniu'] . "</a>";
                    $html .= buildMenu($menu_id, $menu);
                    $html .= "</li>";
                }
            }
            $html .= "</ul>";
        }
        return $html;
    }

    }
?>
```

Controller:

function afisare_domenii_tree() {

```
$this->load->model ( 'new_menu_model' );
$data['domains'] = $this->new_menu_model->buildMenu ();
$this->load->view('new_menu', $data);
```

}

View (using a bootstrap template):

```
<?php echo buildMenu(0, $menu);?>
```

Comment: paste your modal, controller and view. Only then I can figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Your `get_domains` function isn't returning anything?

Comment: I think you got your answer below. Just to be on safer side use mysqli functions or PDO.
If you are using CI then go for the inbuilt Database class and methods. You can even try Active records.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_domains() {
        $result = $this->db->get ( 'domenii' );
        return $result;
```

You already returned from the function above, the code after it will not execute. This should have been more like

```
function get_domains() {
        $result = $this->db->get ( 'domenii' );

        $menu = array(
                'menus' => array(),
                'parent_menus' => array()
        );


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //creates entry into menus array with current menu id ie. $menus['menus'][1]
            $menu['menus'][$row['id_domeniu']] = $row;
            //creates entry into parent_menus array. parent_menus array contains a list of all menus with children
            $menu['parent_menus'][$row['parent']][] = $row['id_domeniu'];
        }
return $menu;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your model. You cannot use `mysql_` functions - Instead take a look at Codeigniter's Query Builder functions here ... http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

```
<?php
class New_menu_model extends CI_Model {
    function get_domains() {
        $result = $this->db->get ( 'domenii' );

        $menu = array(
                'menus' => array(),
                'parent_menus' => array()
        );


        foreach($result->result_array() as $row) 
        {
            //creates entry into menus array with current menu id ie. $menus['menus'][1]
            $menu['menus'][$row['id_domeniu']] = $row;
            //creates entry into parent_menus array. parent_menus array contains a list of all menus with children
            $menu['parent_menus'][$row['parent']][] = $row['id_domeniu'];
        }

        return $menu;
    }

    function buildMenu($parent, $menu) {
        $html = "";
        if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$parent])) {
            $html .= "<ul>";
            foreach ($menu['parent_menus'][$parent] as $menu_id) {
                if (!isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                    $html .= "<li><a href='#'>" . $menu['menus'][$menu_id]['nume_domeniu'] . "</a></li>";
                }
                if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                    $html .= "<li><a href='#'>" . $menu['menus'][$menu_id]['nume_domeniu'] . "</a>";
                    $html .= $this->buildMenu($menu_id, $menu);
                    $html .= "</li>";
                }
            }
            $html .= "</ul>";
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I used this code, but it seems like the view isn't aware of the function in the controller. Not sure if it's also right to be building the menu in the model, instead of the view... I'm a bit confused on how to actually fix this.